# R: convert multiple specific variables into factors

Tags: r

I would like to subset 10 variables from a larger data set, then convert multiple specific variables (2:10) from a data set from continuous to factors, while leaving variable 1 as a continuous variable. This is what I have:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  complete() %>%
  subset("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10") %>%
  lapply([,2:10], factor)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide at least a small subset of your 'data' dataframe with dput(head(data)), and paste it at the beginning of your question. You should also provide the output of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dplyr >= 1.0.0**

Using the new `dplyr::across`:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  complete() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(data, across(2:10, factor))
```

---

**dplyr < 1.0.0**

Since _if, _at, _all have been superseded this will work for older version, but the above should be used.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  complete() %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(2:10, factor)
```

`mutate_at` will apply `factor` to columns `2:10`.

Comment: dplyr mutate: The scoped helpers (all functions ending in _if, _at, or _all) have been superseded by across()!

Comment: Thanks, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `subset()` function takes your data and a logical argument as arguments, but instead, you provided a non-valid argument (several characters within parenthesis, which is not compliant with regular R syntax)

You may be safe with

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  complete() %>%
  select(c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")) %>% as.factor())
```

That reassigns the results to columns 2:10

Not sure without seeing the actual data and output from your attempt, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr across

```
library(dplyr)

#fake data
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 
8L), col2 = c(12L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 19L, 10L, 15L), 
    col3 = c(17L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 18L, 15L, 23L, 13L, 23L
    ), col4 = c(18L, 18L, 16L, 21L, 16L, 25L, 20L, 31L, 22L, 
    33L), col5 = c(22L, 27L, 23L, 27L, 17L, 35L, 28L, 34L, 24L, 
    38L), col6 = c(32L, 34L, 26L, 29L, 23L, 44L, 29L, 39L, 32L, 
    42L), col7 = c(38L, 35L, 29L, 37L, 33L, 48L, 31L, 46L, 41L, 
    47L), col8 = c(42L, 43L, 30L, 46L, 39L, 58L, 34L, 53L, 46L, 
    49L), col9 = c(48L, 44L, 35L, 54L, 49L, 67L, 41L, 56L, 50L, 
    51L), col10 = c(54L, 46L, 44L, 57L, 59L, 75L, 45L, 63L, 51L, 
    56L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df %>%
  select(2:10) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.factor))
```